# Android System WebView 85.0.4183.81 - touchmove event is only firing at 3fps

Tags: android, webview

Yesterday I updated Android System WebView to 85.0.4182.81 on Android 10 phone. Before, the touchmove event was firing 100 fps or so, very smooth. Now it is like 3 FPS.

```css
   var n = 0;
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', function () {
        n++;
        document.body.textContent = n;
    });
```

```html
    Touch and move here
```

You may not be abble to test snippet here so you can test it here: https://ghost.sk/touch.html
Don't test in chrome for android because it has it's own version of webview without this bug.
Is there a way to fix this?

Edit: the workaround is first accepted answer but it is a real issue, here is related bugreport: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1123304

Comment: You can even reproduce this bug in desktop Chrome by toggle device tollbar in devtools and enable Performance record.
Chrome 84 – normal fps - https://i.imgur.com/Vhj7WvA.gif
Chrome 85 – 3 fps - https://i.imgur.com/1ebUt04.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours researching, I found a solution (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1072364):

Try add a `preventDefault()` in `touchmove` event:

```
    var n = 0;
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
        n++;
        document.body.textContent = n;
        e.preventDefault();
    }, {passive: false});
```

Comment: I also needed to add {passive:false} as third argument in addEventListener